# How to define an Alexa Play Directive with MetaData with node.js

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have implemented an Alexa Audio Player skill which plays the audio just fine, but when played on an Echo Show, the name of the song does not show on the display.

I see the documents on Amazon (https://amzn.to/2xzpH4u) refer to a play directive which includes MetaData such as the background image and such, but I'm not sure how to set this up in node.js.

This is the code snippet from my Play intent handler:

```
if (this.event.request.type === 'IntentRequest' || this.event.request.type === 'LaunchRequest') {
    var cardTitle = streamDynamic.subtitle;
    var cardContent = streamDynamic.cardContent;
    var cardImage = streamDynamic.image;
    this.response.cardRenderer(cardTitle, cardContent, cardImage);
}

this.response.speak('Enjoy.').audioPlayerPlay('REPLACE_ALL', streamDynamic.url, streamDynamic.url, null, 0);
this.emit(':responseReady');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your If statement meaning video rendering is supported you build the content of the metadata for the card that is rendered on the device.
So following the documentation cardTitle, Content and Image all have got to be what you are looking for the device to render as a card. You are returning it to be rendered in the this.response statement when all the resources have been provided.
In the example code from Amazon https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/blob/mainline/single-stream/lambda/src/audioAssets.js notice how the card assets are specified. Follow this example and look at the whole project for any other pieces you may be missing.

Comment: I was looking for a simple approach, but after digging into it, I realized it was not something simple.  I did manage to get it working, but I had to use Display Templates and while that solved most of the problem, I am still trying to discover where or how to add a display template for the playing audio.

Comment: Look through April’s heavily commented repo on all manner of display template https://github.com/aprilhamilton/Visual_Tarot

Comment: Excellent information Chuck!  That was exactly what I was looking for.  I have by now gotten most of it working, but this should help me with the final steps I need to accomplish.